# Getting help on Bash's reserved words

Tags: bash, documentation

Is there a way to get the information in [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html) link (it's an index with all (?) the keywords) a and within the first level links in the command line with something like `man` or `help`?

Comment: What are you looking for that is not already in `man bash`?  There is a section in `man bash` that lists reserved words.  There are other sections explaining each one of them.

Comment: @John1024 They are listed in `man bash`, but I can't find a way to get to the details without knowing where they are _a priori_.

Comment: `man bash` is typically displayed with `less` which has powerful search features.   For example, open `man bash` and type `/reserved` and press <ENTER> and you will come to the list of reserved words.  (You may want to read a tutorial on `less` to understand its many powerful features.)

Comment: You can have most (though not all) of that by using `help`. At the command prompt just type `help`, then press space-bar once, then press <tab><tab> and you'll see all the reserved words available in your Bash and select (by typing) the one you want to have the help on. Such `help` is not detailed as the man-page, though. For that, I suppose you can just use the very website you linked ? or why not ?

Comment: @John1024 I should have been clearer. I know about that, but it hardly has any information.

Comment: @alias Just to be clear, are you saying that `man bash` "hardly has any information"?  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @John1024 Yes, more specifically I meant to say with regards to `keywords`, `man bash` hardly has any information.

Comment: @John1024 Actually, I should be more precise: with regards to `keywords`, in the section reserved for keywords, there hardly is any information. I'm sure all that is needed is scattered across its use cases in the docs, but that's not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access exactly the same documentation (including "clickable links") via `info bash`.

So `info bash` -> select "*Indexes*" and then -> "*Reserved Word Index*".

Just for your information (in case you never used `info` pages): search with `Ctrl-s`, go up with `u` and quit with `q`, that should be enough for start; `info info` will give you full description.

Comment: `info` shows me the same information as `help`, it's not showing me the usual `info` interface, looks more like `less`. [Here](https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-473c553032c4.gif)'s a gif of how I see things. Can you confirm that it looks different for you?

Comment: @alias It should look like [that](https://imgur.com/a/v7SA8vn). Which system are you using? Do you have [texinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) installed?

Comment: `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`. It doesn't seem like I do, but I see `info ls` fine. In fact, for all but Bash I see `info` as am I supposed to.

Comment: Hmm, `info /bin/bash` shows me something that looks like `info` is supposed to look like. But it's different from yours. Trying to find what I want here

Comment: Is there a way to search across the all nodes? I'm not finding it.

Comment: @alias I usually only only use `C-s`, there is also `M-/` aka tree-search and `M-}`, `M-{` for searching down, next and previous nodes respectively, `info info` -> searching commands gives the full list.

Answer (score 0):

From [bash(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#RESERVED_WORDS):

> **RESERVED WORDS**
>
>   *Reserved words*
>   are words that have a special meaning to the shell. 
>   The following words are recognized as reserved when unquoted
>   and either the first word of a command (see SHELL GRAMMAR below),
>   the third word of a
>   `case`
>   or
>   `select`
>   command (only
>   `in`
>   is valid),
>   or the third word of a
>   `for`
>   command (only
>   `in`
>   and
>   `do`
>   are valid):
>
> ```
>    ! case  coproc  do done elif else esac fi for  function  if  in  select
>    then until while { } time [[ ]]
> ```

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but the OP says that they know that the man page ***lists*** the keywords, but complain that (as you have shown) it provides ***just** a list,* and no details. Presumably they are looking for information like that presented in the Bash Reference Manual, like [3.2.3 Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) and [3.2.5 Compound Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Compound-Commands.html).

Comment: The OP has a specific request to present the information "in the command line" using "something like`man` or `help`". Your answer just quotes part of the manual.

Comment: @Vilinkameni: Well, to be fair, Renan initially said to use ``man bash``, and I changed that to be the link to the man page, so I guess that’s my bad.